# Insert and Select Last Row from Joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have an insert statement that executes on an internal trigger but the insert statement is inserting into ItemLookups the value from ItemsProduced a, where it does exist instead up updating the a.Casecount and only inserting where it doesnt exist. Where do I incorporate my Update and Set commands in this query? Any sugguestions? Thank you for any help.

```
USE [**]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[spItemLookupNActuals]    Script Date: 09/18/2014 14:30:09 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

-- =============================================

-- =============================================
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[spItemLookupNActuals]
   ON  [dbo].[ItemsProduced]
   AFTER INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;



    INSERT INTO dbo.itemlookup 
            ( 
                        itemnumber, 
                        cases, 
                        [Description], 
                        [Type], 
                        wic, 
                        elc, 
                        totalelc, 
                        lbspercase, 
                        totallbs, 
                        peoplerequired, 
                        schedulehours, 
                        rated, 
                        capacity, 
                        shift, 
                        [DateTime], 
                        [TimeStamp] 
            ) 
SELECT TOP 1 
            a.itemnumber, 
            a.casecount, 
            b.itemdescription, 
            b.divisioncode, 
            b.workcenter, 
            b.laborpercase, 
            a.casecount* b.laborpercase* c.ipcg, 
            b.lbspercase, 
            b.lbspercase* a.casecount, 
            b.personsreqd, 
            d.schedhours, 
            b.poundrating, 
            b.poundrating*d.schedhours, 
            a.shift, 
            a.datetime, 
            a.timestamp 
FROM        itemsproduced a 
INNER JOIN  masteritemlist b 
ON          a.itemnumber = b.itemnumber 
CROSS apply 
            ( 
                     SELECT TOP 1 
                              * 
                     FROM     itemmultipliers2 c 
                     WHERE    c.datetime = a.datetime 
                     ORDER BY c.timestamp DESC)c 
CROSS apply 
            ( 
                     SELECT TOP 1 
                              * 
                     FROM     itemactuals d 
                     WHERE    d.datetime =a.datetime 
                     AND      d.wc = b.workcenter 
                     AND      d.shift= a.shift 
                     ORDER BY d.timestamp DESC) d 
WHERE       NOT EXISTS 
            ( 
                   SELECT * 
                   FROM   itemlookup 
                   WHERE  itemnumber =a.itemnumber 
                   AND    shift=a.shift 
                   AND    datetime = a.datetime) 
   end
```

Comment: maybe split the triggers up for insert/update/delete into seperate ones so you aren't trying to include a record that was just deleted, or inserting a record that was just updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Triggers don't have to be single queries: they can contain more complex logic.  (This is  in answer to your question, "Where do I incorporate my Update and Set commands in this query?")  So you could write conditional logic.  After all, you probably will want to do something different to `ItemLookup` when `ItemsProduced` has a record deleted than when it has a record added.  You can also write separate triggers for different events.

You probably will want to make use of the built-in `inserted` and `deleted` tables that are available within a trigger.  That will let you deal with the values of exactly the records that were affected, rather than trying to determine them by looking at timestamps, as you do in your CROSS APPLY statements.  They are described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx).

(You are also doing a TOP 1 without an ORDER BY on your main query, so what record you get for that "1" can't be predicted.)

Bear in mind, as well, that a trigger gets called once per data-manipulation action (like an INSERT or UPDATE), not once per changed record.  So you could have changes to multiple rows producing only one call of the trigger.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Ann, you provided me with some very helpful pointers and made me think about things differently, in a good way :)  I appreciate your suggestions and expertise.